# Recursive directory renaming

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I need to recursively append the same suffix to all sub-directory names in a directory. What is a simple and safe way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `find` and `rename`:

```
find . -depth -type d -not -name '.' -exec rename -n 's/(.*)/$1_foo/' {} +
```

This will add suffix `_foo` to all directories recursively, `-n` will show the names of the directories that will be changed.

If you are satisfied with the names you can remove the `-n` option to let the action take place:

```
find . -depth -type d -not -name '.' -exec rename 's/(.*)/$1_foo/' {} +
```

Comment: Why do you use `-not -name '.'` here? Will the current working directory be renamed without it?

Comment: `ls bar_foo/` gives `foo`

Comment: `Can't rename ./bar/foo ./bar/foo_foo:`

Comment: @A.B. thats probably you have a directory/file named `foo_foo` already..working for me..

Comment: You're indeed right, it's being listed. Well upvoted it already

Comment: no, your script have created `bar_foo` but there is a subfolder in `bar` with the name `foo` Test your script with this structure: `mkdir bar; mkdir bar/foo`

Comment: @A.B. Fixed....

Comment: Works, great +1 =)